# NLog to Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, nlog

Using the snippet below which uses NLog how can this be done using Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging?

```
    private Logger _logger;
    public NLogger() {            
        _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public void Info(string message) {
        _logger.Info(message);
    }

    public void Warn(string message) {
        _logger.Warn(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
private LogWriter _logger;
public void EntLibLogger()
{
    _logger = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>(); ;
}

public void Info(string message)
{
    LogEntry log = new LogEntry();
    log.Message = message;
    log.Categories.Add("Information");
    log.Priority = Priority.Normal;
    log.Severity = TraceEventType.Information;
    _logger.Write(log);
}

public void Warn(string message)
{
    LogEntry log = new LogEntry();
    log.Message = message;
    log.Categories.Add("Warning");
    log.Priority = Priority.High;
    log.Severity = TraceEventType.Warning;
    _logger.Write(log);
}

public void Error(string message, int EventID, Dictionary<String,String> dictMessage)
{
    LogEntry log = new LogEntry();
    log.Message = message;
    log.Categories.Add("Error");
    log.Priority = Priority.Highest;
    log.Severity = TraceEventType.Error;
    log.EventId = EventID;
    _logger.Write(log, dictMessage);
}
```

Setting up the configuration settings in app.config is the fiddly bit.

My recommendation is to make `EventID` globally unique per call (system documentation always includes the spreadsheet with these numbers and the project/file/line# these occur at). This way, if the app is in production, it is extremely likely that you'll get 1 row from the log and you'll have to be able to identify where in the source this logging call came from. I usually add a dictionary of stuff for local variables and their values for debugging purposes. One place wants the previous values logged, so the audit events always include a dictionary.

The way it logs by default in the database, Entlib stores "category" as a string in both the categories and log table. Severity, priority and EventID are stored as ints. FormattedMessage is a large clump of stuff that is defined in the formatters section, and also includes the contents (the key value pairs) of dictionaries - if used.

Categories is a collection because there may be some times you want to log everything in the database, but certain messages also write to the event log and/or send the dev a text message to get their fanny perpendicular in to work asap. One place I worked at used an Iridium pager to let the designated person know that the servers were down/in trouble, since they liked mountain climbing, they were frequently where no cell coverage existed.

Comment: Thank you for the code and the very detailed explanation. Both have helped me greatly.